# How to make only one group with 2 capture

Tags: regex

I have something like this

> Date;Number;Label;Debit;Credit;more;

I try to make a regex which is going to make group with Date,Label,Debit or Credit

there is an example:

> Date;Number;Label;Debit;;more;

but it could be:

> Date;Number;Label;;Credit;more;

So I try to get only 3 group (it couldn't be Credit and Debit on the same line)

I try this but it's not working:

```
(.*);(?:.*);(.*);{1,2}(.*);{1,2}(?:.*);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `.*` since it matches any characters and you don't want to match semicolons, instead use `[^.]*`, which matches all characters except semicolons.

The resulting regex would be `([^;]*);(?:[^;]*);([^;]*);{1,2}([^;]*);{1,2}(?:.*);`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Dqsfex/1).

Comment: You don't need to unnecessarily group a pattern and then make it non-group by putting `?:`. You can simply write `(?:[^;]*)` as `[^;]*` and overall use a much shorter regex `^([^;]*);[^;]*;([^;]*);;?([^;]*)`. [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55263357/2102956)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use 3 capturing groups. If the match is on the left side of the third group you could capture it using a group and a match what comes after the ; using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

If the match is on the right, you could first match an optional semicolon:

```
^([^;]*);[^;]*;([^;]*);;?([^;]*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^;]*);` Group 1 - match not `;` then `;`
- `[^;]*;` No group, match not ; then ;
- `([^;]*);` Group 2 - match not `;` then `;`
- `;?([^;]+)` Group 3, match optional semi colon, then capture in a group matching not `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOKxoE/1)

If you would also allow no content between the semicolons, you could use `[^;]*` instead.